# Determine if XML contains DOCTYPE

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, doctype

Is there any way to determine, in VB.NET (or C#) whether an XML file has a DOCTYPE element or not?

Thanks!

Comment: DOCTYPE is for HTML?

Comment: No, I'm talking about XML.

Comment: why don't you show the structure of your `XML` this could limit any confusion and or assumptions

Comment: I don't have any structure to my XML. There is no XML yet - I just need to know whether any XML that comes in contains a DOCTYPE!

Answer (score 4):

From msdn documentation [XmlDocument.DocumentType Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.documenttype(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Gets the node containing the DOCTYPE declaration

Sample from the link above:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<!DOCTYPE book [<!ENTITY h 'hardcover'>]>" +
            "<book genre='novel' ISBN='1-861001-57-5'>" +
            "<title>Pride And Prejudice</title>" +
            "<style>&h;</style>" +
            "</book>");

// Display the DocumentType.
Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentType.OuterXml);
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't hard code stuff, just need to look for !DOCTYPE followed by who knows what.

Comment: @user2726536 - Not sure what your comment mean - `DocumentType` returns you content of the `<!DOCTYPE` node for a document - not clear what exactly "hard coded" in that property.

Comment: In the example given in the LoadXML function there's a whole bunch of hard coded stuff. Not clear why you couldn't see that.

Comment: The XmlDocument class has methods to Load documents. This example uses a string to load xml because you've provided no code example to work with. You can just use Load and pass the uri to the file you want to load. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath.

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml("<root>....</root>"); // Or other way to get your XML
        var node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//DOCTYPE");
        if (node != null)
        {
            ... // node.InnerText contains the element text
        }
```